# My program is supposed to read the contents of a user selected file and will call function draw_graph to plot a graph

Tags: python, tuples

My program doesn't print `print( "{:<20s} {:>5d}".format(x,y))` or draw the graph??

```
import pylab

def draw_graph( x, y ):
    '''Plot x vs. y (lists of numbers of same length)'''

    # Title for the graph and labels for the axes
    pylab.title( "Change in Global Mean Temperature" )
    pylab.xlabel( "Year" )
    pylab.ylabel( "Temperature Deviation" )

    # Create and display the plot
    pylab.plot( x, y )
    pylab.show()


def open_file(x):
    climate = open(x, "r")
    return climate


def process_file(climate):
    file = input("Enter a name for the output file: ")
    output_file= open(file, "w")

    tup_list = []
    for line in climate:

        field = line.split()

        year = field[0]
        temperature_deviations = field[1] 
        record = ( year, temperature_deviations )

        tup_list.append( record )

    return climate

    output_file.close()

    print( "{:<10s}  {:>6s}".format( "Year" , "Temperature Deviation"))
    print(30*'-')

    for i in range(line):
        x = tup_list[i][0]
        y = tup_list[i][1]

        print( "{:<20s}  {:>5d}".format(x,y))

    draw_graph(x,y)

def main():
    filename = input("Enter a filename: ")
    try:
        f=open_file(filename)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Invalid file name. Try Again.")
    process_file(f)
    f.close()
main()
```

Comment: My program doesn't print "print( "{:<20s}  {:>5d}".format(x,y))
" or draw the graph?? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have a return statement before, which makes all the code after 'invisible'...

Comment: I'm new to python so I didn't pick up on this.. Do I put the return climate after the draw_graph(x,y)?

Comment: Like in many (any?) language, a return statement terminates a function call. In your case it seems like you return climate but never use that returned value, so just remove that line. If you do need that return value somehow, make sure to put all the rest of the code that needs to be executed before, so YES.